# Is expired but obsolete certificate in a keystore an issue?

Tags: ssl, keystore

I have a keystore which has multiple certificates. One of those certificate is expiring soon, but my apps are not using that certificate any longer. Will it be an issue if i continue using the keystore as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it be an issue if i continue using the keystore as such?

Not if your applications really aren't using it.

Comment: My Apps uses other certificates in the keystore which are still valid. Anyways will update in a couple of weeks when the certificate actually expires.